# How would I go about deleting a node in a linked list without corrupting the list?

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list

```
template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::remove(const T object){
  Node<T> *cur = head;
  while(cur->next != NULL){
    if(cur->next->value == object){
      Node<T>* temp = cur->next->next;
      delete cur->next;
      cur->next = temp;
      s--;
      return true;
    }
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I'm deleting the object after assignment. When I print out the values, the nodes seem to get corrupted. Is this the best way to remove an item from a linked list?

Comment: Probably not relevant: this assumes the object to remove is not in the head.

Comment: It does look ok (apart from the fact that it won't handle 'object' being the first item in the list) - perhaps you need to tell us if Node's destructor does anything 'clever' or show us your 'print the values' code. btw: what is s?

Comment: Handling the head of the list definitely needs more work: apart from not working when the object is the head, it also fails in probably more dramatic ways if the list is empty and thus its head is `NULL`.

Comment: Node has a value and next node. Nodes destructor is just "delete next". I've narrowed it down to this section of code because in my main file, if I comment out the remove call, everything behaves correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nodes destructor is just "delete next".

Oooops. If each node deletes the next one in its destructor, this results in the entire list from that point forward being deleted!

```
  Node<T>* temp = cur->next->next; // the node temp points to is clearly after cur
  delete cur->next; // deletes everything after cur
  cur->next = temp; // temp no longer points to a valid node
```

Comment: Worse. After the dust settles from `delete cur->next;` deleting every node from the one you want to delete on to the end of the list, `temp` now points to freed memory, and `cur->next = temp;` is thus assigning a wild pointer. This will work for a little bit until that freed memory gets reused, then it's off to Undefined Behavior land.

Comment: Haha ohh face palm. I took out the delete next in node and all is fixed with 0 memory leaks. I also fixed the bug where I didnt check the first element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A working version would look more like this:

```
template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::remove(const T object) {

    // Iterate through the list.
    for(Node<T> **cur = &head;; cur = &((*cur)->next)) {
        // Check for list end.
        if(!*cur)
            return false;
        // Check for match.
        if((*cur)->value == object)
            break;
    }

    // Knock out the node.
    Node<T> *temp = (*cur)->next;
    delete *cur;
    *cur = temp;

    // No idea what s does.
    --s;

    return true;
}
```